# How to show progress image after the page load?

Tags: asp.net

I want to perform some operation after the page load, This operation takes some time. I want to show a progress image while the operation is being performed. But the problem is if i call the function in page_load event, my page hangs till the operation is not over. Is there any way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at AJAX Progress bar, here are some links
[aspnet-ajax-with-continuous-progress-bar](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/119029-aspnet-ajax-with-continuous-progress-bar/)

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/RealTime_Progress_Bar_With_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/aspnet_ajax_progress_bar_contr.html